# Android App's Icon is Missing from menu - xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am writing an app and I was just about to implement Google Indexing api and then I have faced the problem. I can install the app and I can see it in app list on my android device(Settings->Applications->MyApp) but I do not see icon in the menu. Also, I can trigger and start the app from CMD with command adb shell am start and the app is working correctly, but if I kill the app I cannot start it again because there is no launch icon.

I have tried to generate .apk and I got the same behavior.

In Manifest file there is

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear: ...but I do not see icon in the menu...
do you mean you do not see it in the homescreen??

If you want to add your app icon to the homescreen you can do it with the following method:

```
    private void AddShortcut()
        {
            var shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityMain));
            shortcutIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionMain);

            var iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.FromContext(
                this, Resource.Drawable.yourAppIcon);

            var intent = new Intent();
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraShortcutIntent, shortcutIntent);
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraShortcutName, "yourAppName");
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraShortcutIconResource, iconResource);
            intent.SetAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure what is the name, here is the picture of menu that I mean:

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RzPwMqisfsw/UDF9LUrsdeI/AAAAAAAAOPs/YJ9Kc8oTUv8/s1600/03.png

Comment: is the icon neither on appscreen nore on homescreen??

Comment: exactly, no icon on homescreen neither on appscreen.

Comment: have you tried my Add Shortcut method in the main activity?

Comment: you have to set the permission: <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

Comment: I have not, it was ok before I have started to implement Google Analytics... And suddenly icon has been disappeared. I'll try and let you know the outcome. Thank you!

Comment: This is fine and it is wirking, I got shortcut on homescreen,  but I still don't see application in All Apps Screen menu.

Comment: also this kind of workaround doesn't work, cannot start app from the shortcut that I have created with AddShortcut() method :(